# Installing pgadmin4 from source code in debian. It has no .configure

Tags: debian, software-installation

I downloaded source code with `.tar.gz` extension. I extracted it

```
   tar -xzf pgamdin4-5-6.tar.gz
```

However, inside `pgadmin4-5-6` directory there is no `configure` file. I think we run `./configure` to create a `Makefile`, so `Makefile` already exist. This is what I get when  I run `ls`

```
DEPENDENCIES
Dockerfile
docs
LICENSE
Make.bat
Makefile
pkg
README.md
requirements.txt
runtime
tools
web
```

I tried

```
 $ make
```

this gives me error:

```
file "build_code_snippet.py", line 4, in <module>
    import builtins
ImportError: No module named builtins
make[1]: [Makefile.sphinx:22: code_snippet] Error 1 (ignored)
sphinx-build -W -b html -d _build/doctrees   . _build/html
make[1]: sphinx-build: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [Makefile.sphinx:47: html] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/tesla/Downloads/pgadmin4-5.4/docs/en_US'
make: *** [Makefile:128: docs] Error 2
```

When I tried `make install` I get this error:

```
   make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.
```

I already installed with python. However, I want to know how I can install from the source code. What am I doing? I already tried from source code last year on a different machine and I have tried recently on my new machine, I wonder how can I install it

Comment: Why don't you install `pgadmin4` via [apt](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-apt/)?

Comment: @Freddy I got this error "E: Package 'pgadmin4' has no installation candidate" when tried with "apt". So I tried source code,  I could not figure out and now I have headache because How come I could not install a pacakge from source code

Comment: @Freddy in my other machine, I installed with python, I will try with python but I still want to learn how to install from source code.

Comment: Read and follow `README.md`.

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at the provided [README file](https://github.com/postgres/pgadmin4/blob/master/README.md). There you can find the steps needed to install pgadmin4 from source. As this is not a classic C/C++ application, the workflow differs and does not contain a step to create a Makefile via `./configure`.

A different way to install, that might be suitable to you, is via pip. Instructions can be found at the [official guide](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-python/)